# How can I show the footer buttons in a TinyMCE dialog

Tags: tinymce-5

I am using TinyMCE 5.6.2 and I have a weird bug with a custom dialog. I have it set to a size of large with a tab panel for the content. I have a header and two buttons setup. When the dialog opens, the buttons are pushed down so that you can just see top few pixels. It looks like some media breakpoint issue because when I resize the window, the buttons become fully visible at a height of 654px and below.

How can I get these buttons to show all the time?

```
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('imageGallery', function (editor, url){
        editor.ui.registry.addButton('imageGallery', {
            icon: 'gallery',
            tooltip: 'Image Gallery',
            onAction: function() {
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Image Gallery',
                    size: 'large',
                    body: {
                        type: 'tabpanel',
                        tabs:[
                            {
                                name: 'upload',
                                title: 'Upload',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'dropzone',
                                        name: 'dropzone'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'site',
                                title: 'My Images',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'htmlpanel',
                                        html: '<div id="myImages" class="img-flex-grid"></div>'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'shared',
                                title: 'Shared',
                                items: [ 
                                    {
                                        type: 'htmlpanel',
                                        html: '<div id="sharedCategories" style="float: left; min-width: 150px; background-color: lightgray; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(34,47,62,.7);"></div><div id="sharedImages" class="img-flex-grid" style="float: right; width: 900px"></div>'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                        ],
                        
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            type: 'submit',
                            text: 'Select',
                            name: 'select',
                            disabled: true,
                            primary: true,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'cancel',
                            text: 'Close'
                    }],
                    onChange: function(dialogInstance, details) {
                        handleInputChange(dialogInstance, details);
                    },
                    onSubmit: function() {
                        handleSubmit();
                    },
                    onTabChange: function(dialogInstance, details) {
                        handleMainTabChange(dialogInstance, details.newTabName)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue, I had to override a CSS class. Because I am accessing TinyMCE via a CDN, I do not see a way to create a custom skin or theme. This is the code that I added to my CSS file.

```
.tox-dialog--width-lg {
    min-height: 650px !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```